# Dict to DataFrame: Value instead of list in DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

[image: dict to dataframe]

How when i convert a dictionary to a dataframe do i stop each value being within a list.

i tried to converting with the pandas from_dict

Answer (score 0):

You can use `orient='records'`.

```py
all_kpi.to_dict(orient='records')
```

Check out the [pandas documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html) for different orientation.